# Benefit of using => operator in declaration

Tags: c#

Recently when I was walking through one of the project source I come across a statement like below.

```
public bool isRestricted => false;
```

Can any one brief me, what is the benefit in using these kind of statements.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's merely syntactic sugar over `public bool isRestricted { get { return false; } }`

Comment: it  provides more compact and simplified structure which explains the basic idea or logic    http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/194010/242481

Comment: Thanks Rob. So there is no other added specialty by doing so..

Answer (score 6):

It is a nice expressive feature, that really suits objects with a lot of small functions. For instance representing business rules. It keeps these types of objects small, easy to read, easy to maintain and understand. Saying that it is mere syntactic sugar and not really useful is wrong in my opinion - if expression bodies are that, then several other features of the language may be considered that as well, such as attributes, auto properties and so on. Expression bodies are really useful for calculation objects, consider the following code:

```
public class PriceCalculator
{
    public double Price(WomensFashionItem item)
    {
        return item.Cost * 1.2;
    }

    public double Price(MensFashionItem item)
    {
        return item.Cost * 1.33 + 10;
    }

    public double Price(ToyItem item)
    {
        if (item.Source == "Taiwan")
        {
            return item.Cost * 2.2;
        }
        else
        {
            return item.Cost * 1.5;
        }
    }
}
```

By employing expression bodies, we can reduce the line count, and in my opinion much easier show our intent here.

```
public class PriceCalculator
{
    public double Price(WomensFashionItem item) => item.Cost * 1.2;
    public double Price(MensFashionItem item) => item.Cost * 1.33 + 10;
    public double Price(ToyItem item) => item.Source == "Taiwan" ? item.Cost * 2.2 : item.Cost * 1.5;
}
```

So from 24 lines of code, to 6, and having a one glance view of all the business rules can be really powerful. I can easily show this code to a domain expert or business owner and they should be able to understand what is going on, and can provide feedback.

Now expression bodies may not be as powerful as say the generic type system, but they certainly can be a nice tool in your toolbox for converting one-liners, or calculated properties into small, easy to understand members.

Comment: To be fair. The last statement could have been simplified in the first code already :)

Comment: in addition I would use =>item.Cost* (item.Source=="Taiwan"?2.2:1.5) :)

Comment: You are right that you could use the conditional operator on the first, but I did the if else to make the difference more clear, as the condition operator is essentially an expression. On your last comment you can offcourse return the factor from the conditional, but here I actually prefer the explicit returning of the calculation, at least for such business logic objects, again I am choosing clarity here, but for different reasons. :)